# Vaadin & Spring Boot - Alternative translations within ValidationMessages.properties are not picked up

Tags: validation, spring-boot, vaadin, bean-validation

I tried to use `BeanFieldGroup<Entity>` in Vaadin Spring Boot, with `javax.validator` and Hibernate validators.

```
@NotBlank(message = "{may.not.null}")
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
private String name;
```

and I created two files: `ValidationMessages_en.properties`:

```
may.not.null=not null
```

and `ValidationMessages_fr.properties`:

```
may.not.null=non null
```

But even when I change the language to French, the validator message is still from `ValidationMessages_en.properties`.

Have any of you any idea about this, please?

Answer (score 0):

The `BeanFieldGroup` creates the BeanValidator with the locale, which is set to the component under validation. Your question does not mention how you create the text field for the `name` property, but let's assume that you create it this way:

```
TextField nameTextField = new TextField("Name");
```

The important factor here is to make sure that the `nameTextField` has correct locale **before** you bind the properties with `BeanFieldGroup` (you can check the locale with `nameTextField.getLocale()`).

So, try to configure your TextField to use the session locale like this:

```
nameTextField.setLocale(UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
```

This piece of code takes the locale from the request ("Accept-Language" request header) and sets it to the field -> the `BeanFieldGroup` will then create BeanValidators with the correct locale and the validation messages are localized (this happens in `BeanFieldGroup#configureField`).

**However use this code only to check that the problem is really only in that your text field does not have correct Locale.** It really does not mean that you have to set the Locale for each and every field out there... That's because in Vaadin  (at least in Vaadin 7) the session (request based) Locale should be inherited by component from the parent. So if you add TextField to the Layout, then the TextField inherits the locale of the Layout, the Layout inherits it from the View and so on (all the way up to `UI.getCurrent().getLocale()` - so check that you have desired locale there). Since the inheritance happens during `addComponent()` call, it's my guess, that, **maybe**, in your case, it would be enough to call the `addComponent()` method (where you are adding the TextField to the layout) **before** you actually use the `BeanFieldGroup` binding.

More info about your problem here: [Remember to set the Locale](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Remember+to+the+set+the+Locale)

Note: I tried to code your issue right now, I faced the same problem as you had and resolved it by moving the addComponent() call before the BeanFieldGroup.